# Why doesn't my git branch match the master branch when it says it's already up to date

Tags: git

I currently have the following branches:

```
  feature/product
  frontend/product
* master
```

I made some changes in a branch feature/product - those changes are good and I wanted to merge.  The same is correct for frontend/product.
What I did was checkout master.  Then

```
git merge feature/product
```

My assumption was that feature/product branch would be merged with master.
From master I then run git status: `nothing to commit, working tree clean`
However my changes from feature/product are not appearing.
When I checkout feature/product then the changes are correctly there.  How can I merge feature/product to display on the master?

Comment: Did you comment your changes on the feature/product branch?

Comment: Meaning git commit -m 'updated media view" if so yes.  It hten said On branch feature/product
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature/product'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean.  @AllanWind

Comment: Did you commit your changes on the feature branch before checkout out to master, also please check your changes with git diff and git log to see commit history!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work-flow is pretty straight forward:

```
$ git checkout -b branch
$ git add files_that_changed
$ git commit -m 'reason why'

$ git checkout master
$ git merge branch
```

After you do `git checkout master`, `git status` would only tell anything interesting if you have a remote configured.  If you run `git status` in your branch it will not tell anything interesting either. Once you merge, and if you have a remote configured, then `git status` will tell you that you have n ahead (I don't remember the exact message).

You can use `git log master..branch` or `git diff master..branch` to the differences before you merge.